# Use ASP.Net WebForm input on second page , then back to original

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net WebForm( EntryForm.aspx) that is populated by textboxes for the user to fill that will be passed to a data base. My Client would like for the user to click a button and a popup to open with all of the information from the entryform textboxes (addressTextBox.txt) in this popup as a formatted page for the user to read and confirm. If correct the user would click a confirm button that would close the popup, go back to the original form and populate a confirmed field before allowing the user to move on to the next step of the form. IF a cancel button is clicked it would simply close the popup and the user can edit thier original entries.

Ok so I decided to try useing an ASP Panel and javascript to show/hide the panel.This seemed simplest. I found a nice script that seems to do what I want it to but having issues.

I am using a Site.Master so I assume I place the script functions inside the content area on the page. as so

```
   <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID ="MainContent" runat="server">
   <script type =" text/javascript">
       function ShowPanel()
       {
       var panel = document.getElementById("<%=ConfirmPanel.ClientID%>");
       panel.style.display = 'block';
       return false;
       }
       </script>
```

And then I am calling it

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitInfoButton" runat="server" Text="Submit Entry"
OnClientClick="return ShowPanel();"/>
```

but the panel never shows on screen.
Any Suggestions?

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Since it's on the same page, you'd better off handling this with javascript.

On your form place a button that will show a hidden div (absolutely positioned with a z-index).

Then, using javascript, copy the values to the labels inside the div. Inside the hidden div you can place a button that will hide the div again (your confirm button) and populate the field (or enable the "continue"-button).

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this before in my applications, I have used the ModalPopupExtender control from the Ajax toolkit and I would highly recommend that you do the same.  The modal popup is actually just a panel with some css applied to it to make it appear modal.  One advantage is you will only have to use .net C# or VB code for everything and not have to mess with javascript.  The other advantage is that it looks more professional to have a modal popup rather than a browser popup.  However, if you are going to stick with javascript, I would try removing the word return from `OnClientClick="return ShowPanel();"` and if that doesn't work, just register the javascript in the code behind and call it from the button's click event in your code behind.